# R: find a condition to replace with NA and redirect to a dataset

Tags: r

I have a dataset require to filter out negative value and replace with NA.

Here is my code:

```
A[ A < 0 ] = NA
```

How can I generate one new dataset like this:

```
A_postive <- A[ A < 0 ] = NA
```

Thanks!

Comment: What does `A` look like? Is `A <- data.frame(id=1:11,value=-5:5)` close enough? And does `A_positive <- replace(A, A < 0, NA)` work?

Comment: @ thelatemail A_positive <- replace(A, A < 0, NA) works! How about replace A<0 or A>10 with NA using replace()?? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @thelatemail for your good comments - the simple way:

```
A_positive <- replace(A, A < 0 | A > 10, NA)
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use `subset` to get the 'value' column with values less than 0 and replace that with `NA` using `transform`.

```
A_positive <- transform(subset(A, value < 0), value = NA)
```